# Scala: http4s giving 401 Unauthorized for same request that works in curl/requests

Tags: scala, curl, http4s, cats-effect, http4s-circe

I tried the following code using `http4s v0.19.0`:

```
import cats.effect._

def usingHttp4s(uri: String, bearerToken: String)(implicit cs: ContextShift[IO]): String = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
    import org.http4s.client.dsl.io._
    import org.http4s.headers._
    import org.http4s.Method._
    import org.http4s._
    import org.http4s.client._


    import org.http4s.client.middleware._

    val blockingEC = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))

    val middlewares = Seq(
      RequestLogger[IO](logHeaders = true, logBody = true, redactHeadersWhen = _ => false)(_),
      FollowRedirect[IO](maxRedirects = 5)(_)
    )

    val client = middlewares.foldRight(JavaNetClientBuilder(blockingEC).create[IO])(_.apply(_))

    val req = GET(
      Uri.unsafeFromString(uri),
      Authorization(Credentials.Token(AuthScheme.Bearer, bearerToken))
    )
    client.expect[String](req).unsafeRunSync()
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) org.http4s.client.UnexpectedStatus: unexpected HTTP status: 401 Unauthorized
[error] org.http4s.client.UnexpectedStatus: unexpected HTTP status: 401 Unauthorized
```

Not only that, my program never exited (do I have to close some client!?) and it also never printed the request even though I hooked up a logging middleware

I next tried @li-haoyi's [request](https://github.com/lihaoyi/requests-scala) library and this returned no error:

```
def usingLiHaoyiRequest(uri: String, bearerToken: String): String =
    requests.get(uri, headers = Iterable("Authorization" -> s"Bearer $bearerToken")).text()
```

The above code works for the same `uri` and same `baseToken` so it can't be that my token is wrong. To be doubly sure, I tried curl:

```
curl -L -H "Authorization: Bearer ${BEARER}" ${URI}
```

This problem also happens in `http4s v0.18.19` (Even with explicit `Json` and accept headers):

```
import io.circle.Json

def usingHttp4s(uri: String, bearerToken: String): Json = {
    import org.http4s.client.dsl.io._
    import org.http4s.headers._
    import org.http4s.Method._
    import org.http4s._
    import org.http4s.client.blaze.Http1Client
    import org.http4s.client.middleware._
    import org.http4s.circe._
    import org.http4s.MediaType._

    val program = for {
      c <- Http1Client[IO]()
      client = FollowRedirect(maxRedirects = 5)(c)
      req = GET(
        Uri.unsafeFromString(uri),
        Authorization(Credentials.Token(AuthScheme.Bearer, bearerToken)),
        Accept(`application/json`)
      )
      res <- client.expect[Json](req)
    } yield res

    program.unsafeRunSync()
  }
```

So my question is:

1. How come both `requests` and `curl` work but `http4s` gives me
   401 for same request?
2. Why does my `http4s` version never exit?
3. Why does the request logger middleware does not log request?

Comment: Just in case, is $bearerToken a value of the form "Bearer xxx" or "xxx" ? It should be the later and is an easily made error ^^

Comment: No, both `usingLihaoyiRequest` and `usingHttp4s` are called with same args

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [gitter room](https://gitter.im/http4s/http4s?at=5c1434be392d8c6f8e618d3d), the bug is in `http4s` which does not forward authorization header to redirects but both curl and requests do (as long as forwarding is to same sub-domain).

Comment: Did you find any way around this? I am also trying to work with http4s, and it is fine with most APIs around the web, but the one I am trying to query (cex.io) still sends me 403s - even with the currently most recent version 0.21.0-M6.

Comment: There we are, I found something out: I had to compile my client with Java 11, not 8. No idea what's the specific influence of the JDK here though.